# Webcam Control can't find new video device

Tags: c#, wpf, webcam

I'm implementing this in C# exactly like it is implemented here
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/285964/WPF-Webcam-Control
but FindDevice() can't find external webcam usb 2.0 which I've connected. but it sees my laptop's webcam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved. Both my laptop's webcam and external webcam have the same name "usb 2.0". That's why it didn't see external webcam. I tried to stop my laptop's webcam from settings, so i have only one  webcam-external. Now it finds.